Functions whose product with every $L^1$ function is $L^1$

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure and $f$ a measurable function whose
product with any integrable function is integrable: $$
\int|g|\,{\rm{d}}\mu<\infty\implies \int|fg|\,{\rm{d}}\mu<\infty. $$
Does this imply $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$?

Observation 1) $f$ amounts to a well-defined functional $g\mapsto\int fg\,{\rm{d}}\mu$ on $L^1(\mu)$. If one argues that this is bounded, the Riesz representation theorem can be invoked.
Observation 2) Limiting to $g\in\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$, a simple induction shows that $f\in L^n(\mu)$ for every positive integer $n$. Thus $f$ lies in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}L^n(\mu)$, but this intersection may be strictly larger than $L^\infty(\mu)$. So I wonder if the greater freedom that we have with $g$ yields a positive answer to the question.

One should perhaps put on record that your query touches on a subject ($\alpha$-duality for (sequence and) function spaces, more precisely Köthe-Dieudonné duality) which was studied in great depth and generality in the middle of the last century.  Specifically you are asking for the $\alpha$-dual of $L^1$.  Suitable references are easy to find using a search machine.

Yes, the answer to your question is positive. For any function $f\in L_1$, such that $f \not\in L_\infty$, we will explicitly find $g\in L_1$, such that $fg \not\in L_1$.
Let us take arbitrary non-negative $f\in L_1, f\not\in L_\infty$. Let $A_k := f^{-1}([k^2, \infty))$, and define
$$
g := \sum_k \frac{1}{k^2} \mathbf{1}_{A_k}/\mu(A_k).
$$
Clearly $\|g\|_1 \leq \sum k^{-2} < \infty$, yet $\int fg \,\mathrm{d}\mu = \sum k^{-2} \frac{1}{\mu(A_k)} \int_{A_k} f \,\mathrm{d} \mu \geq \sum k^{-2} \cdot k^2 = \infty$.

Similarly to MaoWao’s comment on the other answer, this works assming only that $\mu$ is semifinite, as you can replace $A_k$ with its subset of finite positive measure in the definition of $g$.

I think this also a direct consequence of the uniform boundedness principle (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Corollaries):
$T_n \colon g \mapsto \int \, f g \mathbb{1}_{\vert f \vert \leq n}  \,\mathrm{d}\mu$ is a bounded linear operator $L^1(\mu) \to \mathbb{R}$ and we have the pointwise convergence $T_n(g) \to T(g) = \int \, f g \, \mathrm{d}\mu$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $g \in L^1(\mu)$ by the assumption $\int \, \vert f g \vert \, \mathrm{d}\mu < \infty$ and the dominated convergence theorem. Therefore $T$ is also a bounded operator, i.e. $f \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$.
Thanks to @MaoWao and @DavidGao for this hopefully now correct  further remark: The statement "For all $\mathcal{F}$-measurable $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, $\int|fg|\,{\rm{d}}\mu<\infty$ for all $g \in L^1(\mu)$ implies $f \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$" is equivalent to the negation of "There is a sequence of disjoint $\mathcal{F}$-measurable sets $(A_n)_n$ such that for any $n$ it is $\mu(A_n) = +\infty$ and there is no $\mathcal{F}$-measurable subset $B \subseteq A_n$ with $0 < \mu(B) < \infty$" (+) for any measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$.
For one direction, assume that (+) does not hold and that $\int|fg|\,{\rm{d}}\mu<\infty$ for all $g \in L^1(\mu)$. Then there is a (finite) $C > 0$ such that $\Vert f g \Vert_{L^1(\mu)} \leq C \Vert g \Vert_{L^1(\mu)}$ for all $g \in L^1(\mu)$ by the proof above.
Suppose $g \notin L^{\infty}(\mu)$.
Let $A_n := \{\vert f \vert \in [n, n+1)\}$. Then by assumption there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq N$ there is a measurable $B_n \subseteq A_n$ with $0 < \mu(B_n) < +\infty$.
Thus $n \mu(B_n) \leq \Vert f \mathbb{1}_{B_n} \Vert_{L^1(\mu)} \leq C \mu(B_n)$ for all $n \geq N$, a contradiction.
For the other direction, assume (+). Let $f = \sum_{n} n \mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ for the sets $A_n$ from (+). Then $\int|fg|\,{\rm{d}}\mu = 0 < \infty$ for all $g \in L^1(\mu)$, but $f \notin L^{\infty}(\mu)$.

You only need that the measure is semi-finite. If $f$ is not essentially bounded, then $A_n={\lvert f\rvert\geq n}$ has positive measure for every $n\in\mathbb N$. If there exists $B_n\subset A_n$ with $0<\mu(A_n)<\infty$, then $\lVert f, \mathrm{sgn}(f)1_{B_n}\rVert_1/\lVert \mathrm{sgn}(f)1_{B_n}\rVert_1\to\infty$ in contradiction to the closed graph theorem. Such a set $B_n$ (for arbitrary measurable $A_n$ with positive measure) exists exactly when $\mu$ is semi-finite.

@MaoWao Thank you for the extension. Even more sharp I think would then be that the whole statement is actually equivalent to "every measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A) = +\infty$ which has no subset $B \subseteq A$ with $0 < \mu(B) < +\infty$ has finite cardinality".

Technically, your counterexample for the non-$\sigma$-finite case does not work, since your $\sigma$-algebra is too small - it only has finitely many sets, so any measurable function necessarily only takes finitely many values, whence bounded. (In this case, only two values, one on $[0, 1/2]$ and one on $(1/2, 1]$.) But you could get a counterexample, by, say taking $[0, 1]$, the $\sigma$-algebra $P([0, 1])$, and the measure that sends any nonempty set to infinity. Then the only element of $L^1$ is the zero function, and any function on $[0, 1]$ would be measurable.

As such, your proposed equivalent condition is incorrect. This really doesn’t have much to do with the cardinality of measurable sets. Likely, the equivalent condition might be something like “there exists infinitely many mutually disjoint measurable sets $A_i$ s.t. each has infinite measure and no subset of positive finite measure.”

@DavidGao Sorry, this was of course complete nonsense when interpreted literally. It's now hopefully correct due to your correction and as general as it gets.

In your penultimate paragraph, I believe you meant $0 < \mu(B_n) < +\infty$ instead of $\mu(A_n)$. Other than that, I think this is now correct.
